# Security risks with distributing files with bittorrent

Tags: networking, bittorrent

So I am evaluating different options for distributing very large files between several sites without completely crashing my servers and my IT infrastructure.

My best option so far seems to be some sort of bittorrent solution. However I am not sure if this solution is safe security wise. Is anyone aware of any known security flaws in the bittorrent protocol that would make it possible to intercept files without having access to the torrent file or the tracker?

My hope is that it would be sufficient to send the only the torrent file over vpn or using encrypted email and then letting the rest go over internet as usual.

"EDIT"
To clarify, the receivers of these files will not always be the same persons/computers so it will not work with having some sort of syncronized folder.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to do, but maybe this approach will suit your needs? https://www.getsync.com/ It's a dropbox alternative based on the bittorrent protocol.

Comment: That is really cool. However this will not work for this issue since it will not always be the same computers receiving the files. It will differ from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, without the .torrent file the clients won't be able to download the torrent data. But I haven't researched this so I may be wrong. The community, please correct me if that's the case.

As an extra measure to be able to notice any abuses you could set up your tracker with passkeys (in other words make the tracker 'private') so that each torrent file is unique to each user you are sending it to.

That way you will be able to see which users downloaded/uploaded how much data and from which IPs, and from there draw conclusions if a user may have given the .torrent file to other users.

Then you can easily blacklist the abuser's passkey thus making the .torrent file useless.

The .torrent files should be created using the `Private` flag so that DHT, PEX and other peer lookup methods won't work for it.

Comment: Thanks! That is actually a very good idea. I suppose that you can also restrict usage of the files from everyone outside a certain ip range as well.

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote your answer. Not enough rep yet...

Comment: Correct. You can configure your tracker to allow only specific IP ranges to be able to 'announce' to it.